# Why uniroot() gives wrong result?

Tags: r

```
options(scipen=999)
fff=function(x)588 * x * 1000000 - 5000
>uniroot(fff, lower=0.0000000000001, upper=1, extendInt = "yes",maxiter = 1000000000)$root 
[1] 0.0000000000001


> fff(0.0000085)
[1] -2
> fff(0.0000086)
[1] 56.8
```

the right value for `fff()` is something between `0.0000085` and `0.0000086`, but why uniroot is returning me  `0.0000000000001` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the default value for the `tol` argument to uniroot is `tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25` - and the answer you got is within this tolerance.

Note also that the *object* returned by uniroot contains error estimation:

```
> uniroot(fff, lower=0.0000000000001, upper=1, extendInt = "yes",maxiter = 1000000000)$estim.prec
[1] 0.00006103516
```

You can set `tol` explicitly and get a better answer:

```
> uniroot(fff, lower=0.0000000000001, upper=1, extendInt = "yes",maxiter = 1000000000, tol=0.0000001)$root
[1] 0.000008503401
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the configuration of `tol` since the precision of your desired result cannot be captured by the default tolerance `tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25`.

In other words, you need to improve the resolution, which can be done by setting `tol = .Machine$double.eps` instead for example

```
r <- uniroot(
  fff,
  lower = 0.0000000000001,
  upper = 1,
  extendInt = "yes",
  maxiter = 1000000000,
  tol = .Machine$double.eps
)$root
```

such that

```
> r
[1] 8.503401e-06

> fff(r)
[1] -9.094947e-13
```